# Convert C array Record to Delphi

Tags: c, delphi, pascal

I Have this C code:

```
typedef enum { STB_Expression_Max} STB_OKAO_EXPRESSION;

typedef struct {STB_INT32 anScore[STB_Expression_Max];} STB_FRAME_RESULT_EXPRESSION;
```

How can I convert the above code to array in Delphi?

Comment: The structure (with the code as shown) will have a zero-sized array, is that by design? Is it supposed to be a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member)?

Comment: As for your question, what have you tried? How did (or didn't) your attempt work? What problems do you have with the code you tried?

Comment: This doesn't seem unclear. What difficulty do you have. Do you know either of the languages.

Comment: If you are having problems, and must convert more, please read this: [Pitfalls of converting](http://www.rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-convert.html)

Comment: @RudyVelthuis In case you are interested, I edited into your deleted answer an explanation as to why an enum was used rather than a C constant.

Comment: I saw it. I don't think that #defines of simple numerical values are evil (they are more or less like true constants in Pascal), although macros can be, but it is still not what enums are meant for, IMO, even if it is to work around a limitation. Anyway, I'll probably amend the article a bit. FWIW, that is not exactly a flexible array. A flexible array in C99+ is declared as a `[]` array, not as a `[0]` array. The purpose is the same though.

Comment: I doubt this is really the code you have. I suspect you've omitted other enum values that appeared before that one in the list. That would make the array suitable for holding scores for each of the other kinds of expressions. Since you've removed those declarations, though, the remaining code looks like nonsense.

Comment: @rudy Nothing here suggests C99, and prior to that standard zero length arrays were used for flexible array members. Your opinions on macros aren't relevant to my point. I'm just explaining why you sometimes see enums used that way. You may prefer to use macros. That's fine. But it's a point of fact that enum values are constant expressions. That was the point I was making. It can't be disputed.

Comment: @David: C99 (IOW, roundabout 18 years ago) was the first standard with the concept of flexible array members, IIRC. And that standard uses `[]` syntax for them. That is why I wrote that. I know why I sometimes see enums that way. I still think it is not what enums are for, even if they are a convenient way to define true constants, and that is why I called it abuse. Single-value enums don't, er, enumerate.IMO, enums with binary values, e.g. 0x0001, 0x0002, 0x0004, 0x0008 etc. are not really proper enums either, especially since they are not used as enums.

Comment: I'm glad that you understand now

Comment: @David: I understood from the start. I still think it is abuse of enums, even if I see it being done quite often.

Comment: You are welcome to your opinion. I just explained the facts.

Comment: As far as enums with specified ordinality go, bitflags and the like, they aren't enumerations. The feature is badly named. But they get used in that way because they are the best thing for the job. History explains why it is this way. When working with C you have to stop thinking of enum as an enumeration.

Answer (score 1):

It could be:

```pascal
const
  STB_Expression_Max = 0;

type
  STB_INT32 = ?; { ← define here }
  STB_FRAME_RESULT_EXPRESSION = record
    anScore: array[0..STB_Expression_Max] of STB_INT32;
  end;
```

Comment: I reverted Rudy's edit, which does not compile. Note that the original answer, whilst compiling, declares an array of length 1, whereas the C code declares a flexible array member. That point needs some explanation.

Comment: @David: you are right. Don't know what I was thinking.